# How to make Glassfish 4.0 WebService use TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, glassfish-4, tls1.2

Good Day, Everyone,
   I have a JAX-WS (Metro) Web Service running on Glassfish 4.0 that receives inbound https messages. All has been running great (over TLSv1.0), but now the vendor sending us messages wants to require that they only be sent over TLSv1.1 or TLSv1.2. GF4.0 uses JDK7 by default which supports TLSv1.2 but it is disabled by default. How do you turn this on so that the Web Service can still receive messages??   I can do this in a POJO client (outbound), but am having issues configuring the server to do the same (inbound).

I have tried going into the GF Admin Console\Configurations\server-config\JVM Settings and adding JVM Option -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 but this seems to have no affect...

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Were you able to get a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

TLS 1.2 should be enabled by default. You can disable TLS and TLS1.1 using the following asadmin commands

```
asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.ssl.tls-enabled=false 

asadmin set configs.config.server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-listener-2.ssl.tls11-enabled=false
```

If you have other HTTPS listeners configured other than the default then replace http-listener-2 with the name of your http-listener and server-config with the name of your configuration e.g. default-config.